# Get Article list by subscription

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I am trying to make a filter with which I could get subscription records

Entity 'Subscription'

```
export class Subscription {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;
  @Column('uuid')
  userId: string;
  @Column('uuid')
  targetUserId: string;
  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

Filter

```
applyFilter(query: QueryArticle, qb: SelectQueryBuilder<Article>, userId?: string) {
    if (query.filter) {
      switch (query.filter) {
        ....
        case 'subscriptions':
          qb.select(
            `article.authorId WHERE targetUserId IN (SELECT targetUserId FROM Subscription WHERE userId=${userId})`,
          );
          break;
      }
    }
    return qb;
  }
```

SQL code

```sql
Select * FROM article WHERE authorId=targetUserId IN (SELECT targetUserId FROM Subscription WHERE userId=userId)
```

Error

```
syntax error at or near "f5779e5" +3974ms
QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near "f5779e5"
```

How can I get all the posts of people followed by a person use TypeORM?

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: Is this realy the generated SQL code? This looks suspicious (assignment in the WHERE)
Select * FROM article `WHERE authorId=targetUserId IN` (SELECT targetUserId FROM Subscription WHERE userId=userId)

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT DO WHAT YOU ARE DOING**. You are risking a [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection). If you really want to do a manual query, you can do `manager.query`:

```
const output = manager.query('article."authorId" WHERE "targetUserId" IN (SELECT "targetUserId" FROM Subscription WHERE "userId" = :userId)',
  { userId: userId }
);
```

> Notice the second parameter that contains parameters which is referenced by key with `:userId`. If you're using template strings for queries, you're probably doing something wrong.

If you want to use the QueryBuilder, then it's going to look a little different (more info on [QueryBuilder here](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder))

```
const output = articleRepo.createQueryBuilder('article')
  .select('article.authorId')
  .where('article."authorId" IN (SELECT "targetUserId" FROM subscription WHERE "userId" = :userId)',
    { userId: userId }
  )
  .getRawMany(); // If you remove the .select('article.authorId'), you can use .getMany()
```